# How to specific scroll width in <FlatList/> in React Native Expo

Tags: css, react-native, expo

trying to create a day picker with a flat list. Basically i render multiple weeks that i can scroll through eg week1, week2, week3 etc. I want a single week to take up the width of the device, and when i am scrolling, I want it to "snap" to a week so I will always see the days "sun-sat" and nothing else. But I currently see like 1.75 weeks per screen width. I tried experimenting with justifyContent and flexGrow but it makes it too wide. I just need to scroll one item/ week at a time. [image]

```
const Week = ({ item, selectedId, setSelectedId }) => (
    <View style={styles.weekContainer}>
        {item.days.map((day) => {
            return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => setSelectedId(day.id)}
                    style={[
                        day.id == selectedId ? styles.unselectedDay : styles.selectedDay,
                    ]}
                    key={day.id}
                >
                    <Text
                        style={[
                            day.id == selectedId ? styles.unselectedDayText : styles.selectedDayText
                        ]}
                    >
                        {day.name}
                    </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            )
        })}
    </View>
);

export const DateHeader = () => {
    const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState(today.toLocaleDateString());
    const width = Dimensions.get('window').width
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <Week
                item={item}
                selectedId={selectedId}
                setSelectedId={setSelectedId}
            />
        );
    }
    return (<>
        <FlatList
            data={weeks}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
            extraData={selectedId}
            horizontal={true}
            inverted={true}
            style={styles.flatList}
            showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
            decelerationRate={0}
            snapToInterval={width}
            snapToAlignment={'center'}

        />
    </>)
}
```

Styles:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    flatList: {
        flexGrow: 0,
    },
    weekContainer: {
        flexGrow: 1,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderColor:'red',
        borderWidth: '2px',

    },
    unselectedDay: {
        fontSize: 16,
        padding: 10,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#6e3b6e',
    },
    selectedDay: {
        fontSize: 16,
        padding: 10,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#f9c2ff',
    },
    unselectedDayText: {
        textColor: 'white'
    },
    selectedDayText: {
        textColor: 'black'
    },
});
```

Thank you in advance!